# How can I extract multiple rows from a single one having 4 columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, row

I'm having a issue with a query in Postgres. I need to extract from a table with a specific pattern using a pure select. For example I have:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

From this table I want to select something like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2 | null | null |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | null |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I don't really have a clue on how to do it efficiently. Anyone can help? Many thanks

Comment: is 1, 2, 3, 4 the only combination, or can there be something else. Also, is column A always less than Column B etc

Answer (score 1):

You can *cross join* with a list of integers and use a conditional expression:

```
with n as (select * from(values(1),(2),(3),(4))x(n))
select 
    case when n >= cola then cola end cola,
    case when n >= colb then colb end colb,
    case when n >= colc then colc end colc,
    case when n >= cold then cold end cold
from n
cross join t;
```

[working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EzkpWPgR)